# WebObjects and jQuery problems with umlauts

Tags: jquery, encoding, webobjects

iam trying to connect WebObjects and jQuery. The problem I have is that if i want to get a response from a WOComponent with jQuery (.ajax() , .load(), .get()) the german umlauts are not rendered correctly. I get questionmarks an so on.

Is there anybody that had the same problems with Webobjects an jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

What encoding is your WebObjects application using to send responses in? Check with Firebug. If you are using Wonder then you should set the property

*er.extensions.ERXApplication.DefaultEncoding=UTF-8*

to be sure that everything is using UTF-8.

Comment: Thx for the response. I checked the header response from WebObjects.       The default encoding was not set. So now I set the Response Headers in the appendToResponse method temporalily for the response.  woResponse.setHeader("text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1", "content-type"); Now jQuery knows how to convert the umlauts.